# Need help in finding Spark SQL code equivalent to SAS Code

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sas, databricks, code-conversion

I have a piece of code which I need to convert from SAS to Spark SQL. I want to know what is the equivalent function for as that in SAS

SAS Code:

```
DATA NEW_TABLE;
SET
SOURCE_TABLE1
SOURCE_TABLE2
;
RUN;
```

I do understand that it's creating a new table by joining the existing two source tables. But not able to understand how that converts to SQL

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL syntax, that would be a UNION or UNION ALL.

```
create table new_table as
select * from source_table1
union
select * from source_table2
```

The above assumes that the columns in both source tables are identical.